# Java: MySQL Data truncation: Incorrect double value: '' for column

Tags: java, mysql, truncation

Since we are working with a ton of data, a method is generating the query.

```
        ...
        switch(operation) {
        case "insert":                 
            query +="INSERT INTO " + table + " SET ";
            for(int i=0; i<columns.size(); i++) {
                query += "`"+columns.get(i)+"`='"+values.get(i)+"',";
            }
            query=query.substring(0, query.length()-1); //to remove the last " , " from the string
            query += ";";
        break;
        ...
```

This method generates this error message when we run the query generated by it:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect double value: '' for column 'HITELKERET' at row 1
```

The query string generated by the method is:

```
 INSERT INTO szallvev

 SET `NEV2`='',`BANKSZAMLA`='         -          -         ',
    `BANK1`='',
    `ORSZAG`='',
    `BANK2`='',
    `IBAN`='',
    `SWIFT`='',
    `IRSZAM`='',
    `VAROS`='',
    `UTCA`='',
    `KTJELLEG`='0',
    `HAZSZAM`='',
    `EPULET`='',
    `LEPCSOHAZ`='',
    `EMELET`='',
    `AJTO`='',
    `ADOSZAM`='',
    `KOZADOSZAM`='',
    `UGYINTEZO`='',
    `EMAIL`='',
    `TELEFON`='',
    `MOBIL`='',
    `INTERNET`='',
    `FAX`='',
    `FIZMOD`='0',
    `CSOPADO`='',
    `MUNKASZAM`='',
    `HITELKERET`='',
    `DEVARSZINT`='0',
    `KEDV1`='0',
    `NAPOK`='',
    `ELADO`='0',
    `UZLETKOTO`='',
    `AZONOSITO`='test',
    `NEV1`='test';
```

The problem is, when I copy this string from the Java console, and paste it inside a MySQL editor (I use SQLYOG), the query executes without any errors.

Comment: and yes, this is why hand-crafting insert statements is a terrible idea - use a PreparedStatement

Comment: Column type of HITELKERET is what?

Comment: it is a float(32)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I'm a complete idiot. I can just leave the blank fields, so the SQL won't try reading a double from ''. 
I changed my method to look like this:

```
    switch(operation) {
        case "insert":                 
            query +="INSERT INTO " + table + " SET ";
            for(int i=0; i<columns.size(); i++) {
                val = values.get(i);
                if(val.length()>0) { // notice the if(), when the field has no value, it wont be put into the query string.
                    col = columns.get(i);
                    query+="`"+col+"` = '"+val+"',";
                    if(i%3==0) query+="\n";
                }

            }
            query=query.substring(0, query.length()-1);
            query += ";";
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error tips and my experience, you didn't get the correct data type for the **HITELKERET** column when you were splicing the query string.

It seems like The **HITELKERET** field should be float type in your database table.

Please make sure **HITELKERET** column is not an empty string, at least the default 0

Comment: It was a float when the error came, then I changed it to double (the error is still here)
The problem is, that this isnt a field that is required to fill, and I want it to stay empty, if possible (seems like it's not so far)

Comment: @Fusyoo stay empty does't mean  empty String "".You can simply not mention this column in your sql String

Comment: @Fusyoo The database's float or double type cannot identify an empty string，it's going to be an error

Comment: I tried to work around the empty string error, and I found the solution. Thanks a lot!